# UPDATE query inside a while loop php

Tags: php, select, mysqli, sql-update

I need to grab images from an URL then change the URL into another. Here is my code for that. But it is not working as I expected. It is do change only one image. Others won't.

Here is my code,

```
<?php

include_once('db-conn.php');

$query = "SELECT my_image_url AS image FROM my_image";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);

if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $img_url = $row['image'];
        $content = file_get_contents($img_url);
        $img_name = basename($img_url);
        file_put_contents($img_name, $content);
        $query = "UPDATE `my_image` SET `my_image_url` = 'http://localhost/img/".$img_name."'";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you mean it updates all images, or just one? If all you need a `where` clause.

Comment: Use `where` condition in your update query to update particulate row

Comment: You probably want `SELECT my_image_url AS image, id FROM my_image` then use the `id` to update the particular row. You also should use prepared statements, this could potentially get you injected.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, Yes I need a condition here. Now it is working fine after the condition (where clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to the below one so as to update the column for the grabbed value

```
$query = "UPDATE `my_image` 
  SET `my_image_url` = 'http://localhost/img/".$img_name."' 
  WHERE `my_image_url` = {$img_url}";
```

Comment: I made a small change here, I used '".$img_url."' instead of {$img_url}. Now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a condition to your `update` query

```
$query = "UPDATE `my_image` SET `my_image_url` = 'http://localhost/img/".$img_name."' where (YOUR CONDITION HERE)";
```

Comment: Explain why so.